# How to take portlet preferences correctly in Liferay?

Tags: java, liferay, preferences, portlet, liferay-6

If a portlet is a web application, then why portlet preferences are taken from ServletRequest (at request scope)?

http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/util/PortalUtil.html#getPreferences(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)

How is it possible to take preferences object at application scope?

**UPDATE 1**

I am obtaining portlet preferences in the following way. Is it correct? prefs member below is at application scope.

```
private synchronized void setupPreferences(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // creating preferences
    if( prefs == null ) {

        prefs = PortalUtil.getPreferences(request);
        if( prefs != null ) {
            System.out.println("Preferences were taken from request");
        }

        String portletResource = ParamUtil.getString(request, "portletResource");
        if (Validator.isNotNull(portletResource)) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Replacing preferences from 'portletRecource' parameter");
                prefs = PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getPortletSetup(request, portletResource);
            } catch (SystemException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (PortalException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if( prefs == null ) {
            System.out.println("Preferences were NOT obtained yet");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Preferences are OK");
        }

    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I am using also servlets and static objects in my application. Static objects are in application scope as one can know. I wonder can I keep portlet preferences object in some static object or I need to reobtain it from request each time?

Actually I already assumed this and it works but I wish to know is it correct?

Answer (score 6):

```
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.getPreferences(HttpServletRequest)
```

is just a utility method.

If you take a look at implementation you'll see what is going on

```
public PortletPreferences getPreferences(HttpServletRequest request) {
    RenderRequest renderRequest = (RenderRequest)request.getAttribute(
        JavaConstants.JAVAX_PORTLET_REQUEST);

    PortletPreferences preferences = null;

    if (renderRequest != null) {
        PortletPreferencesWrapper preferencesWrapper =
            (PortletPreferencesWrapper)renderRequest.getPreferences();

        preferences = preferencesWrapper.getPreferencesImpl();
    }

    return preferences;
}
```

In your handlers you can/should use request.getPreferences(). "request" being implementation of PortletRequest, RenderRequest, ActionRequest, ResourceRequest.

UPDATW:

If you need to access specific portlet preferneces from servlet, you could try with

```
com.liferay.portlet.PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getPortletSetup(HttpServletRequest p_request, String p_portletId)
```

It is static method, and returns PortletPreferences, so knowing your portlet's id and having request object you should be able to get preferences.

Comment: Anyway in you example(s) the preferences are also taken from requests of different kinds. Does this mean that the preferences are of request scope? In my application I need to access preferences not only from portlet rendering but from other places too.

Comment: Yes, portlet preferences are stored in portlet request. You can access them in your render, action, resource handlers, or any other method that you pass request to. What "other places" do you mean, please update question with this.

Comment: The question is why are they stored in request if they are application scoped? "Other places" are servlets and static objects, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're not subclassing Liferay's **MVCPortlet** class?

Anyway is the request object that you're passing to setupPreferences originally a **PortletRequest** object that you've gotten the **HttpServletRequest** out of?

If so you can just call **PortletRequest.getPreferences()**;

Comment: The `request` object can be both `PortletRequest` or normal `HttpServletRequest` passing to normal servlet.